# Measure theory example

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I have one example considering Jordan measure of a set which I am not really sure about.
So here it is:Find the Jordan meaure of a set bounded with:
$$z^2\le x^2+y^2, x^2+y^2\ge y, x^2+y^2\le 2y, |x|\le y\sqrt{3}$$.
So here, I need to find value of triple integral over a constant function. Bound for $z$ are $0\le z\le x^2+y^2$. I get confused when it comes to finding boundaries in $OXY$ plane. Should i use cylindrical coordinates or not?